# Formulario y envio de mail PHP (no envia campos checkbox)

Tags: php, email

Tengo un problemilla.. tengo un formulario en HTML y un PHP de envio de mail, el mail se envia y se recibe bien, hasta ahí todo bien.

El problema es al recibir el mail, los inputs que tengo de tipo checkbox (desayunos, cenas, suplatoria y mascota) no se ven reflejados en el mail y no entiendo el porqué. Mi intención es que se vean si han sido checkeados o no en el formulario. He tratado de buscar respuesta y nada. No se si debería usar algun otro lenguaje de apoyo o usar directamente otro. Ahí va el código!

```js
<?php

//llamando a los campos..

$nombre = $_POST{'nombre'};
$apellido1 = $_POST{'apellido1'};
$apellido2 = $_POST{'apellido2'};
$telefono = $_POST{'telefono'};
$mail = $_POST{'mail'};
$mensaje = $_POST{'cuerpo_mensaje'};
$desayunos = $_POST{'desayunos'};
$cenas = $_POST{'cenas'};
$suplatoria = $_POST{'suplatoria'};
$mascota = $_POST{'mascota'};

//datos para el correo

$destinatario = "isaacmarti.g@gmail.com";
$asunto = "Reserva Posada Magoria";

$carta = "$mensaje\n";



//enviando mensaje...

mail($destinatario, $asunto, $carta);
?>
```

```html
    <form action="enviar.php" method="post">
        <div id="row">
            <div id="info">
                <div>
                    <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Introduce tu Nombre.." required>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="nombre">Primer Apellido</label>
                    <input type="text" id="nombre" name="apellido1" placeholder="Introduce tu Nombre.." required>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="nombre">Segundo Apellido</label>
                    <input type="text" id="nombre" name="apellido2" placeholder="Introduce tu Apellido.." required>
                </div>
                <div>
                        <label for="telefono">Teléfono</label>
                        <input type="phone" id="telefono"  name="telefono" placeholder="Introduce tu teléfono.." required>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="mail">Mail</label>
                    <input type="mail" id="telefono"  name="mail" placeholder="Introduce tu teléfono.." required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="añadidos">
                <div>
                    <label  for="desayunos">Desayunos buffet +6€ por desayuno</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="desayunos" name="desayunos">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label   for="cenas">Cenas +10/16€ por cena</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="cenas" name="cenas">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label  for="suplatoria">Cama Suplatoria +15€</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="suplatoria" name="suplatoria">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label  for="mascota">Mascota +4€</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="mascota" name="mascota">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="enviar">
            <div>
                <textarea name="cuerpo_mensaje" id="cuerpo_mensaje">
                    ¡Hola! Me gustaría reservar una habitación (DOBLE/DOS CAMAS) para (NUMERO DE PERSONAS) persona/s el dia   (. ./. ./. . . .)
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="enviar"value="RESERVAR" id="boton_enviar">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: te funciona esto??? `$_POST{'nombre'};` Es la primera vez que lo veo. Esto en general se pone con corchetes, no con llaves. `$_POST['nombre'];`

Comment: Si que me funciona si.. pero lo cambiaré. Es la primera vez que toco PHP. El cuerpo del mensaje si se ve reflejado como antes pero los inputs checkbox siguen sin verse en el mail de envío.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no se ven reflejados porque nunca los envias.

```
$destinatario = "isaacmarti.g@gmail.com";
$asunto = "Reserva Posada Magoria";

$carta = "$mensaje\n";

//enviando mensaje...

mail($destinatario, $asunto, $carta);
```

En la instruccion de mail pones el destinatario, asunto y carta, y resulta que $carta es una copia de $mensaje, pero no incluyes los valores de las otras variables.

Para que te funcione, podrias hacer:

```
$carta = "$mensaje\n$desayunos\n$cenas\n$suplatoria\n$mascotas";
```

esto es un ejemplo, pues luego tendras que modificar el valor de $carta para adecuarlo a un formato html o texto que a ti te interese. De momento esto deberia enviarte valores true y espacios en blanco. Probablemente Te interese añadirlo como tablas, algo tipo:

```
$carta = "$mensaje\ndesayunos: $desayunos\ncenas: $cenas\nsuplatoria: $suplatoria\nmascotas: $mascotas";
```

Comment: Vaya puse el PHP antiguo. Yo lo tenia así                                               $carta = "$mensaje\n";
$carta .= "$desayunos\n";
$carta .= "$cenas\n";
$carta .= "$suplatoria\n";
$carta .= "$mascota\n";                                                                                          Ahora veo el fallo.. pense que con la concanetación serviria, ¡Voy a probarlo!

Comment: No.. sigue sin funcionar.. solo me lanza el mensaje, pero no los inputs checkbox.

Comment: como te digo en la respuesta, `De momento esto deberia enviarte valores true y espacios en blanco`. Esto significa que tendras que adecuar el valor de la salida de los checkbox, analizando si estan vacios y mostrar un valor adecuado. Algo tipo true/false, o si/no, o activado/desactivado... Pero tienes que analizarlo antes y asignarle luego el valor correspondiente.

Answer (score 1):

Además de lo que te comenta Jakala debes tener en cuenta que los campos `checkbox` no *checkeados* efectivamente no se envían, por lo tanto tendrás que prever eso en la recepción de los mismos.

Dos opciones posibles serían:

**a) Dar un valor por defecto para el caso de no *`checked`*:**

```
        <div id="añadidos">
            <div>
                <label  for="desayunos">Desayunos buffet +6€ por desayuno</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="desayunos" value="no">
                <input type="checkbox" id="desayunos" value="si" name="desayunos">

            </div>
            <div>
                <label   for="cenas">Cenas +10/16€ por cena</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="cenas" value="no">
                <input type="checkbox" id="cenas" value="si" name="cenas">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label  for="suplatoria">Cama Suplatoria +15€</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="suplatoria" value="no">
                <input type="checkbox" id="suplatoria" value="si" name="suplatoria">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label  for="mascota">Mascota +4€</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="mascota" value="no">
                <input type="checkbox" id="mascota" value="si" name="mascota">
            </div>
        </div>
```

De esta forma, los checks no seleccionados te llegaran con valor **no** y los seleccionados con valor **si**, pues los campos `hidden` serán sobreescritos por los `checkbox`.

**b) Verificar si llega el valor de cada campo:**

```
<?php 
$desayunos = isset($_POST['desayunos'])?'si':'no';
$cenas = isset($_POST['cenas'])?'si':'no';
$suplatoria = isset($_POST['suplatoria'])?'si':'no';
$mascota = isset($_POST['mascota'])?'si':'no';
```

Basta con preguntar primero si ha llegado el campo esperado y asignar el valor adecuado según el caso.

> Ambas opciones son muy básicas, en entornos de producción (o
>   aprendizaje avanzado) se deberían implementar métodos más robustos o versátiles
>   para la gestión de formularios.